# Is it safe to charge Galaxy j7 using Galaxy A5 charger?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-a5, samsung-galaxy-j7

A5 has 2900mA battery and a charger with fast charging capability and j7 has 3000mA battery with normal charging.

Can I use that to fast charge the Galaxy j7?

Comment: j7 mobile charging is done by 1.5mA or 2mA charger .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galaxy J7 isn't rated for Fast Charge support either on [Samsung's](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/phones/all-other-phones/samsung-galaxy-j7-16gb-t-mobile-white-sm-j700tzwatmb/#specs) [sites](http://www.samsung.com/in/microsite/galaxyj/j5-j7/spec.html) or other sites that host specs, and comes with a measly 5V 1.5A charger (for both the [2015](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j7-review-1307p2.php) and [2016](http://www.phonearena.com/reviews/Samsung-Galaxy-J7-2016-Review_id4211/page/4) versions). Adding the fact that it targets the lower end of the market, it's safe to guess it does not support Fast Charge. In comparison, A5 is at a higher end and supports Qualcomm Quick Charge 2.0.

You should still be able to use the charger, just not getting fast charge from it.